# Str Attribute has no keys when trying to write dictionary to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to write a dictionary into a CSV file using the following code:

```
def condense_data(in_file, out_file, city):
"""
This function takes full data from the specified input file
and writes the condensed data to a specified output file. The city
argument determines how the input file will be parsed.

HINT: See the cell below to see how the arguments are structured!
"""

with open(out_file, 'w') as f_out, open(in_file, 'r') as f_in:
    # set up csv DictWriter object - writer requires column names for the
    # first row as the "fieldnames" argument

    out_colnames = ['duration', 'month', 'hour', 'day_of_week', 'user_type']        
    trip_writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames = out_colnames)
    trip_writer.writeheader()

    ## TODO: set up csv DictReader object ##
    trip_reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)

    # collect data from and process each row
    for row in trip_reader:
        # set up a dictionary to hold the values for the cleaned and trimmed
        # data point
        new_point = {}

        ## TODO: use the helper functions to get the cleaned data from  ##
        ## the original data dictionaries.                              ##
        ## Note that the keys for the new_point dictionary should match ##
        ## the column names set in the DictWriter object above.         ##

        duration = duration_in_mins(row, city)
        month, hour, day_of_week = time_of_trip(row, city)
        user_type = type_of_user(row, city)
        new_point = {'duration': duration, 'month': month, 'hour': hour,
                     'day_of_week': day_of_week, 'user_type': user_type}



        print(new_point) # Works fine till here, I am able print the right output
        trip_writer.writerows(new_point) # throws an error
```

Below is the error that is being thrown:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         8 
>         9 for city, filenames in city_info.items():
>   ---> 10     condense_data(filenames['in_file'], filenames['out_file'], city)
>        11     print_first_point(filenames['out_file'])
>
> in condense_data(in_file, out_file,
>   city)
>        38             ## see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects ##
>        39             print(new_point)
>   ---> 40             trip_writer.writerows(new_point)
>        41 
>        42
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/csv.py in writerows(self, rowdicts)
>       156 
>       157     def writerows(self, rowdicts):
>   --> 158         return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
>       159 
>       160 # Guard Sniffer's type checking against builds that exclude complex()
>
> /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/csv.py in _dict_to_list(self, rowdict)
>       146     def _dict_to_list(self, rowdict):
>       147         if self.extrasaction == "raise":
>   --> 148             wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
>       149             if wrong_fields:
>       150                 raise ValueError("dict contains fields not in fieldnames: "
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'

I did look it this type of questions on Stack Overflow but none of them helped.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using `writerows()` where you should use `writerow()`, because you're trying to write one row, not a list of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I can't believed I missed that. I went through the docs like 10 times

Comment: Happened to me when writing a dict of dicts, instead of a list of dicts. I switched to `for key in maindict: writerow(maindict[key])`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying every solution proposed here and everywhere- and still keep getting "'str' object has no attribute 'keys'" error.  I can't get writerow(s) to work with my data, so I just converted the dictionary to a pandas dataframe and then exported the pd dataframe to csv.

Example dictionary:

```
    {'Time': [1622178352.7355769,1622178356.1456945,1622178358.7532275,1622178361.4067194,1622178393.741893,1622178397.9731262],
   'H': ['HV', 'HV', 'HV', 'HV', 'HV', 'HV'],
   'Horizon_dist': ['14.01', '13.50', '13.50', '13.50', '18.50', '18.50'],
   'Horizon_units': ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
   'Azimuth': ['126.20', '129.10', '128.70', '128.80', '109.50', '109.90'],
   'Azimuth_units': ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
   'Inclination': ['-0.50', '-0.70', '-1.60', '-1.70', '7.20', '-0.00'],
   'Inclination_units': ['D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'],
   'Range': ['14.01', '13.50', '13.50', '13.50', '18.50', '18.50'],
   'Range_units': ['F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
   'Tilt': ['48', '46', '41', '4F', '6F', '4B']}
```

and then convert to pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(adict)
df.to_csv(r'data.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: Yours is actually a good solution.
Another solution is use     
for key, value in mydict.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])